# A simple Dao integration test not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, tdd, hibernate-generic-dao

This is a very simple test about persisting a transient Person Object in the database and then verifying that the object saved in the
database is the same as the transient Person object.
Here goes the test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/daoIntegration-test.xml")
@Transactional
public class HibernatePersonDaoIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private PersonDao PersonDao;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    public void shouldSavePerson() {
        //Given
        Person person = new Person();

        //When
        PersonDao.savePerson(person);

        //Then ----THIS ASSERTION PASSES!!!
        assertThat(person.getId(), notNullValue());
        //And ----THIS ONE FAILS!!!
        Person persistedPerson = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from table_Person", Person.class);
        assertThat(persistedPerson, is(person));
    }
```

My daoIntegration-test.xml

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL"/>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Domain class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_Person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "seq_table", table = "GENERATOR_TABLE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "seq_table")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Long id;
    private String personFirstName;
...
```

The first assertion passes, but the second one fails, I'm making a silly mistake somewhere but don't know where!!!

Comment: person and persistedPerson are two different instances, so they are not equal. They may be equivalent. e.g Person.ID = persistedPerson.ID etc. You could override the equals operator for the Person class, but seeing as you haven't yet that might cause problems, so checking a few Person Properties might be best.

Comment: I had equals and hashcode overridden, the problem was with the entity not saved in the database, flushing it solved the problem as suggested by @Tomasz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First possible problem

The second assertions fails simply because it returns a different instance of `Person` object. Since you are not (?) defining `equals()`/`hashCode()`, the `is()` matcher fails.

Implement them (this is generally a good idea with Hibernate).

### Second possible problem

The first assertion passes because Hibernate fetched id from `seq_table` but haven't yet flushed the entity itself. This means the entity is in first level cache, but not yet in the database. Thus when you are querying the database directly using JDBC:

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from table_Person", Person.class);
```

The record is not found. Call `flush()` after saving an entity or query the object using JPA. Hibernate is clever enough to `flush()` prior querying.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing a `SELECT *` query, which returns one object only if there's one row in the database.

If the query does not return exactly one row, or does not return exactly one object, then a `IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException` is thrown.

Are you certain that an exception isn't thrown?

Does your Person class implement equals and hashCode [correctly](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf)?  If the is() method depends on these, it can't be any better than your implementation allows.